# Get actions on recaptcha enterprise

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to build a dashboard based on data from recaptcha enterprise. I only got the score metrics data, but not the actions data.

Is it possible to get the actions that can be found on recaptcha dashboard on GCP?

[image]

By using this code, I can get the score metrics. I also notice that it includes challenge metrics, but it's weird there is no data at all included in it. I wonder if the challenge and score metrics is the same?

```
from google.cloud import recaptchaenterprise_v1

def sample_get_metrics():
    # Create a client
    client = recaptchaenterprise_v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = recaptchaenterprise_v1.GetMetricsRequest(
           name="name_value",
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.get_metrics(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

```
start_time {
  seconds: 1649055600
}
score_metrics {
  overall_metrics {
    score_buckets {
      key: 0
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
challenge_metrics {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ScoreMetrics`](https://cloud.google.com/static/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1#scoremetrics) returned from [`GetMetrics`](https://cloud.google.com/static/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1#google.cloud.recaptchaenterprise.v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseService.GetMetrics) may have both `overall_metrics` as well as `action_metrics`, where you would be interested in the latter.

> `action_metrics` | `map<string, ScoreDistribution>`
> Action-based metrics. The map key is the action name which specified by the site owners at time of the "execute" client-side call. Populated only for SCORE keys.

Note that these are only available for `SCORE` keys, as opposed to `CHECKBOX` keys. https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/keys